Unable to login to ubuntu 18.04 via Dell laptop
I am using a dell laptop, recent time I am unable to login to my laptop even with valid password, Please help me how to resolve this issue.
Here is the screenshot enter image description here

Ubuntu 18.04 LTS reached End of Standard Support last year, and is thus off-topic on this site.  You can use ESM/Pro support options (cost maybe involved) if you wish but community support (such as this site) no longer exists, though SE Unix & Linux allow all Ubuntu questions too.  Please see https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic as Canonical provide ESM/Pro services.

This question is similar to: How do I reset a lost administrative password?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

You can login via Virtual Console and re-install Desktop Environment it will fix
